# Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found in template/theme/index.php on line xxx

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

i upgrade template 2.5 to 3.0, template upgrade but come the following error.

**Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found in template/theme/index.php on line xxx**

Comment: please add the code that is on that line causing the error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`JParameter` was removed in Joomla 3.0 and now either `JForm` or in most cases `JRegistry` should be used.

So use the following code, and change to suit your own needs

```
$jparams = new JRegistry();
$variable = $jparams->get('param_name');
```