# Joomla - Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm trying to upgrade Joomla 2.5.22 to 3.5.1, and last time I checked the progress bar, it was 86 %. I looked away for a moment and when I came back to check I saw the below error message.

> Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found in
>   /home/mywebsite/public_html/plugins/system/bigshotgoogleanalytics/bigshotgoogleanalytics.php on line 24

What is the cause of this error and how would it be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found in template/theme/index.php on line xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225816/fatal-error-class-jparameter-not-found-in-template-theme-index-php-on-line-xx)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla can't find JParameter Class, so you have to use

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );
```

before using JParameter class

Comment: `jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );` didn't work for me. By the way, Inside `bigshotgoogleanalytics.php` file I even found your statement already at the beginning.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225816/fatal-error-class-jparameter-not-found-in-template-theme-index-php-on-line-xx) solved my issues.  Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

`bigshotanalytics` is one of those plugins that cause a blank page or, at best, a fatal error when updating Joomla. This is because of its old code. I suggest you move the tracking code to your template. You can also add the tracking code to a custom HTML module (after [removing the encapsulating div through an override](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-div-tag-from-custom-html-modules)) and then assign the module to a position in your template (the position should be in the  section of the HTML).

Now to answer your question, Joomla no longer uses JParameter - it uses JRegistry instead. So something like:

```
$jparameter = new JParameter('param1');
```

Should be changed to:

```
$jregistry= new JRegistry();
$jparameter = $jregistry->get('param1');
```